# How to get phrase tags in Stanford CoreNLP?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, phrase, parse-tree

If I want to get phrase tags corresponding each word, how to I get this?

For example :

In this sentence,

> My dog also likes eating sausage.

I can get a parse tree in Stanford NLP such as

```
(ROOT (S (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog)) (ADVP (RB also)) (VP (VBZ likes) (NP (JJ eating) (NN sausage))) (. .)))
```

In the above situtation, I want to get phrase tags corresponding each word like

```
(My - NP), (dog - NP), (also - ADVP), (likes - VP), ...
```

Is there any method for this simple extraction for phrase tags?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
//I guess this is how you get your parse tree.
Tree tree = sentAnno.get(TreeAnnotation.class);

//The children of a Tree annotation is an array of trees.
Tree[] children = parent.children() 

//Check the label of any sub tree to see whether it is what you want (a phrase)
for (Tree child: children){
   if (child.value().equals("NP")){// set your rule of defining Phrase here
          List<Tree> leaves = child.getLeaves(); //leaves correspond to the tokens
          for (Tree leaf : leaves){ 
            List<Word> words = leaf.yieldWords();
            for (Word word: words)
                System.out.print(String.format("(%s - NP),",word.word()));
          }
   }
}
```

The code is not fully tested but I think it roughly do what you need. And what's more is I didn't write anything about recursively visit the subtrees but I believe you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm basically continuing the original question. Using Stanza, I would like to obtain a phrase tag per word in a text.

```
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,pos,constituency')
doc = nlp('My dog also likes eating sausage.')
tree = doc.sentences[0].constituency
```

The parse tree obtained is:

```
(ROOT (S (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog)) (ADVP (RB also)) (VP (VBZ likes) (S (VP (VBG eating) (NP (NN sausage))))) (. .)))
```

but would like phrase tags (exactly as in the original question):

```
(My - NP), (dog - NP), (also - ADVP), (likes - VP), ...
```

Has this been solved? Thanks!