# Stanford parser - count of tags

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, phrase

I have been using the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) for CFG analysis. I can get the output displayed as a tree, but what I really want is a count of tags.

So I can get out, for example (taken from [another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373557/how-to-get-phrase-tags-in-stanford-corenlp) on Stack Overflow):

```
(ROOT (S (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog)) (ADVP (RB also)) (VP (VBZ likes) (NP (JJ eating) (NN sausage))) (. .)))
```

But what I really want is a count of the tags output in a CSV file:

```
PRP - 1
JJ - 1
```

Is this possible with the Stanford parser, particularly as I want to process several text files, or should I use a different program?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easily possible.

You will need:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
```

I assume from the other question you have an existing Tree object already.
I suspect you only want a list with the leave nodes (PRP, NN, RB... in your example), but you could do it for every node in general.

Then iterate over all nodes and count only the leaves:

```
Tree tree = ...
for (int i = 1; i < tree.size(); i++) {
  Tree node = tree.getNodeNumber(i);

  if (node.isLeaf()) {
    // count here
  }
}
```

The counting is done using a HashMap, you will find many examples on stackoverflow here.
Basically start with a Hashmap, using the tag as key and the tag-count as value.

edit: sorry, corrected a negation mistake in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer, while being correct, iterates over all nodes in the parse tree. While there is no readily available method that returns the POS tag counts, you can directly get leaf nodes using methods in the `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Trees` class as follows:

(*I am using Guava's `Function` for a little extra elegance in the code, but a simple for loop will work just as well.*)

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class); // parse tree of the sentence
List<CoreLabel> labels = Trees.taggedLeafLabels(tree); // returns the labels of the leaves in a Tree, augmented with POS tags.
List<String> tags = Lists.transform(labels, getPOSTag);
for (String tag : tags)
    Collections.frequency(tags, tag);
```

where

```
Function<CoreLabel, String> getPOSTag = new Function<CoreLabel, String>() {
    public String apply(CoreLabel core_label) { return core_label.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class); }
};
```

Comment: Elegant answer, indeed!

Comment: Thanks for your help both of you. Sorry if this is obvious, but this would mean creating a Java module then? At present I have just been running it in Terminal command line (eg, java -mx200m edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -retainTMPSubcategories -outputFormat "wordsAndTags,penn,typedDependencies" englishPCFG.ser.gz mumbai.txt)

Comment: Yes, you need your own code. Even though the authors of Stanford NLP have provided a lot of flexibility for CLI usage, for anything beyond the straight-forward output of the parse results, you will usually need to use their API (which, by the way, is very well documented).