# Stanford nlp: Parse Tree

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have this sentence: `My dog also likes eating sausage.`

And I get the following parse tree:

```
(ROOT
 (S
   (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
   (ADVP (RB also))
   (VP (VBZ likes)
     (S
       (VP (VBG eating)
        (NP (NN sausage)))))
(. .)))
```

How do I get only the grammatical category, namely: NP,ADVP,VP, etc?

I tried with this code:

```
  Tree t=sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
  t.labels();
```

Comment: Do you need only chunks for a sentence ?

Comment: I would like to retrieve only those parts of the parse tree!

Comment: I want something like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373557/how-to-get-phrase-tags-in-stanford-corenlp)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by grammatical category? The leaf level annotations are Part of Speech tags. Are you simply looking for the annotations one level above those?

Comment: Yes, it should be to a level above! I would be interested are those that extract these: [link](http://s27.postimg.org/97ngmxg0j/Immagine.png)

Comment: What you want is a chunker, not a parser. You could try [YamCha](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/yamcha/).

Answer (score 4):

From a sentence annotation you can get various typed collections of dependent words. This may be the 'next level up' you're looking for.

```
Tree tree = sentenceAnnotation.get(TreeAnnotation.class);                             
// print the tree if needed                                                           
SemanticGraph basic = sentenceAnnotation.get(BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);      
Collection<TypedDependency> deps = basic.typedDependencies();                         
for (TypedDependency typedDep : deps) {                                               
    GrammaticalRelation reln = typedDep.reln();                                       
    String type = reln.toString();                                                    
}                                                                                     

SemanticGraph colapsed = sentenceAnnotation                                           
        .get(CollapsedDependenciesAnnotation.class);                          
Collection<TypedDependency> deps = colapsed.typedDependencies();                      
for (TypedDependency typedDep : deps) {                                               
    GrammaticalRelation reln = typedDep.reln();                                       
    String type = reln.toString();                                                    
}                                                                                     

SemanticGraph ccProcessed = sentenceAnnotation                                        
        .get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);               
Collection<TypedDependency> deps = ccProcessed.typedDependencies();                   
for (TypedDependency typedDep : deps) {                                               
    GrammaticalRelation reln = typedDep.reln();                                       
    String type = reln.toString();                                                    
}
```